# Concept vs. Typename Parameter in Template Template

Tags: c++, templates, standards, undefined-behavior, c++23

I was curious if this is defined behavior in C++23 to have a `template`-`template` that takes a `typename`, and be able to insert a `template` which accepts a `concept` (which `accepts` a `typename`)?

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
concept MyConcept = std::is_integral_v<T> || std::is_floating_point_v<T>;

template<template<typename> typename TT>
struct A {
    template<typename T>
    using Type = TT<T>;
};


template<MyConcept T>
struct B {
    T bb;
};

int main(int argc, char** args)
{
    auto a = A<B>{}; // Ok? Compiles with gcc 13.2.1 and clang-16.0.6
    auto b = decltype(a)::Type<int>{};
    return 0;
}
```

The converse also seems to compile which makes me more suspicious

```
template<template<MyConcept> typename TT>
struct A {
    template<typename T>
    using Type = TT<T>;
};


template<typename T>
struct B {
    T bb;
};

int main(int argc, char** args)
{
    auto a = A<B>{}; // Ok? Compiles with gcc 13.2.1 and clang-16.0.6
    auto b = decltype(a)::Type<int>{};
    return 0;
}
```

Here, under a certain reading, we should accept a `template` into the `template`-`template` *iff* that template accepts a `MyConcept`, but `B`'s `template` is unconstrained?

Are either of these examples undefined behavior, or are they behaving as the standard defines?

Thank you!

Comment: Updated example

Comment: The updated example looks good. And it compiles with all compilers. And I don't see any reason why it should be undefined behavior.

Comment: @user12002570 I would like to build a library which may end up relying on this behavior, and I just want to check that its defined. The reason I am suspicious is because a lot of seemingly innocuous things are UB, for example, names that begin with an underscore, which many programs have https://godbolt.org/z/GjhYhx4n3 will anything come of it? Probably not, even cppreference seems to contradict itself over weather or not you can specialize `std::char_traits`
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std

Comment: Concepts are a relativity new feature and this seems like an odd corner case, which is why I ask

Comment: Yup, I understand. C++ is full of surprises. Many simple looking things are UB in C++. So it's ok to wonder if this is. My main point is that have you tried like reading the standard to see if this is UB or not. The question in itself is good enough and I only want that people should atleast once try reading the standard by themselves to figure out. Otherwise people can just post any(infinite number) of working code snippet and start asking if that snippet is UB just because it looks suspicious to them.

Comment: Your right, I honestly should have, I am looking at it now (never really looked at it much before, a little intimidating tbh, anyway just built the document), it looks like example 4 under section 13.4.4 paragraph 3 of the C++23 standard might shows exactly the case, and example 3 looks relevant as well.

Comment: Here is a [list of standard document pdfs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links#C++_Language_and_library_references) of different c++ versions which I use very frequently so that you don't have to built the document again and again. Can download the document pdf from there directly. That should speed up the process.

Comment: @user12002570 Thanks! That should be on https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the publicly available working draft of the C++23 standard it seems like this is *defined* behavior and is correct. Example 4 under § 13.4.4 paragraph 3  seems to show exactly this, from the standard:

```
template<typename T> concept C = requires (T t) { t.f(); };
template<typename T> concept D = C<T> && requires (T t) { t.g(); };
template<template<C> class P> struct S { };
template<C> struct X { };
template<D> struct Y { };
template<typename T> struct Z { };

S<X> s1; // OK, X and P have equivalent constraints
S<Y> s2; // error: P is not at least as specialized as Y
S<Z> s3; // OK, P is at least as specialized as Z
```

Also this from example 2 looked relevant:

```
template<auto n> class D { /* ... */ };
//...
template<template<int> class R> class Z { /* ... */ };
//...
Z<D> zd; // OK
```